# Knockout 2.0 parameters from bind in incorrect order?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

With Knockout 2.0 using this data-bind:

```
data-bind="click: $root.deleteSomeEntity.bind($data, $parent)"
```

in the Knockout viewmodel JavaScript the first argument in

```
self.deleteSomeEntity = function (data, parent) {
    // perform deletion
}
```

seems to be the parent rather than the data.

Is there a reason for this behavior or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call `bind` the first parameter will be the value of `this`.  So, in your call `this` will be `$data` and the first argument will be `$parent`.

If `$root` is `$parent` in this case, then you can just do:

`$root.deleteSomeEntity.bind($root)`

KO will pass the data as the first parameter and `this` will be set to `$root`.

If `$parent` is not `$root` (and you likely don't want to rely on `this` being a different object that `$root` in your method on root), then you would do something like:

`$root.deleteSomeEntity.bind($root, $data, $parent)`

Otherwise, there are certainly ways to make sure that you have the proper `this` within your view model.  It depends on your structure though.

Comment: Following your suggestions: http://jsfiddle.net/6MmWs/5/ however when clicking Delete and the `self.deleteContactPhone = function(viewModel, phone, contact)` the viewModel is a phone, phone is a contact, and contact is also a phone. `this` is currently the viewmodel.

Comment: You would want it more like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6MmWs/6/.  A couple things to mention.  `remove` is a function that is available on an observableArray.  I switched your `phones` arrays to be observable, so that you have `remove` and your UI updates when one is removed.

Comment: The other thing is that want your function signature to just be `function(phone, contact)`.  The first parameter to `bind` is the target, which is used to control the value of `this` when your function runs.  So, it is not actually an argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks for this information ryan, I'm not sure I really agree with KO using that first argument to magically become `this` but that's your guys decision. The documentation of this is completely unclear however. I would strongly recommend updating the documentation on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html to include the topics we covered here. I went back looked over this and the only reference I found at all about this was "with this being redefined to mean something else in event handlers" which i'm not even sure directly matches our topic or whether that's general javascript

Comment: Just a note: It is not a KO decision to use the first argument of `bind` as `this`.  `bind` is natively supported in most newer browsers and KO adds this support for browsers that don't have it available.  Some info on bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I can look at updating the `click` docs to provide clearer information on this one.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer thanks for that link I had never seen that, so now i'll take back my criticism of KO on this and move to where it belongs that i just think its a stupid choice of javascript to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `bind()`? By default, if you just write the name of the javascript function as the click event Knockout will pass `$data` as the first argument and the event as the second.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html (Note 1&2)

Why bother with `bind()` when you can simply do this:

```
data-bind="click: function() {$root.deleteSomeEntity($data, $parent)}"
```

Comment: That code seems to be executed without clicking for me. It is inside a data-bind="foreach: ..." if that changes anything.

Comment: Oh of course it does! Sorry about that, I have edited the code so a `function()` is wrapped around the click binding.  This should work as expected now.

Comment: It is just a style thing.  Many people don't like putting anonymous functions in their markup.  This is one of the things that turns people off when they are starting in KO, especially when they are used to a more unobtrusive approach.  It works fine either way, although I prefer making sure that `this` is set appropriately in the view model itself.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer: I don't like putting anonymous functions in my markup either, but setting `this` correctly with the `.bind()` syntax tripped me up, so soniic's way ended up being the *only* way that would work for me. YMMV

Comment: @JimG. If you have a specific example, then I might be able to help sort it out.  There generally should be a way to make it work without using an anonymous function.